# Get assembly name of referenced project

Tags: c#, reference, assembly-name

Let's say I have project A and project B. I have them in the same solution and A references B and uses B as a kinda slave process. I don't want to hardcode the assembly name of B but I'm wondering how to query the assembly name in project A so I can execute the assembly of project B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

typeof(B).Assembly.GetName().Name;

Comment: That should be an object from project B `typeof(objectFromProjectB)`